# Planning for post PhD career

Tags: postdocs, industry, physics

I'm currently a Master's student in physics and I will begin my PhD apps in the next few months. I should graduate from my Masters in Spring 2022. I'm looking to do theoretical work. I'm applying to places in Europe - specifically UK, Germany and France, and the US. I'm leaning towards a European PhD because of the length of the PhD in the US and because I don't particularly see myself living in the US in the long term. Within Europe I'd prefer a PhD/job after that in the UK because I think my girlfriend may also be getting a relatively stable job there.

My question is the following.

1. I understand that there is a disadvantage to apply to the US for postdocs and such, with a UK/European PhD. How bad is this?
2. How likely is it that I can get some non-Academia job in the UK after my PhD (if I pursue it there, or elsewhere in Europe)?

I guess what I'm worried about is getting a European PhD and neither being able to get jobs in academia nor in industry (either of which, preferably in the UK). My first preference (at this point) would be to do a post doc somewhere in Europe but I'm reading a lot about the job market in academia and I'm realizing that a stable, permanent job in academia might be a lot harder than I used to think, so I'm just weighing my options here. By industry jobs I also mean jobs outside of physics- such as those in finance and data science and what not.

Comment: Please ask one question per post.  Questions about non-academic jobs are off-topic.  Access to the US job market is mostly a matter of visa availability, which could easily change during your PhD.  Predictions are useless.